# Can response stuck here in interceptor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors

I wonder if response that comes through this interceptor can stuck here if it doesn't match filter? Is it passed forward or do I need to make alternative case with `next.handle`?

```
  intercept(httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(httpRequest).pipe(
      filter((event) => event instanceof HttpResponse && event.body && event.body.response),
      map((event: any) => event.clone({ body: event.body.response }))
    );
  }
```

Comment: Yes it can get stuck, whenever the event is not matching your `filter` condition. You should only use the map and stick the filter condition into a classic `if` inside that map handler.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu thank you, I applied your suggestion.

Comment: You should only modify the event whenever it matches the condition, otherwise return the event unmodified from the map. You should be good.